# understanding where rails authenticity_token is necessary (static page login?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, csrf

I have been trying to work out if I can have a login form on my static homepage.  I would like to have some static pages and it would be great to have a login form on them. I spent some time getting more familiar with the authenticity_token that is generated with form_tag and although I realize we want to generally check all requests that aren't GET requests I feel like it might be possible to leave it out for a login because we aren't trusting the user with anything until after they are logged in.  If a malicious site tried to use CSRF at this point it would need to know the login and password at which point the user is compromised anyway.

I definitely don't want to open up any security holes in my application and I appreciate all that rails does to keep this working, but in this situation am I right to think I can just submit a form without the token?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the token is so that data cannot easily enter your system unless it is coming directly from that form. When a user visits the site, they get a cookie that matches the token in the form. When the form is submitted, those tokens must match.

If someone can submit the data from outside the form, you are opening up the potential for a script to make continuous login attempts. It's fairly easy to write something that would automate going to your site, getting a cookie and logging in using the form, but it's definitely more work. Think of it as another layer of security that you can have without negatively affecting your users.